# How to turn off callbacks when changing virtual attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, paperclip

My model has an 'url' virtual parameter with a big amount of data at the link. The same model has a paperclip attachment: so when a new instance is created, it can contain the data for attachment or url-string from where the object should download it. I want to encapsulate all the checking if it is url-based data or the raw one from controller:

```
@music = @order.build_music(params[:soundtrack])
if @music.save
    format.html { redirect_to edit_order_path(@order) }
    format.js 
else
    format.html {render :action => 'new'}
    format.js
end
```

I want My music model check if there is a url virtual parameter is set and if it so download it asynchronously:

```
has_attached_file :soundfile

after_save :check_if_url

def self.downloadSoundtrack(id, url)
    find(id).update_column(:soundfile, open(url))
end

private
    def check_if_url
        if self.url.present?
            Soundtrack.delay.downloadSoundtrack(self.id, self.url)
        end
    end
```

but update_column does not work with virtual parameters, and I can't use save 'cuz it will fire after_save callback recusivelly. Plz, help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it won't fire callbacks

```
Model.where(id: id).update_all(soundfile: open(url))
```

Comment: just to clear the matter: soundfile is not a database field - it is a created by paperclip virtual attribute. So I don't think update_all will work

Answer (score 0):

[API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-save)
: The validation process on `save` can be skipped by passing `validate: false`.

Comment: aye, that's right. *validation* would be skipped, but I need after_save callback to be skipped